# Rails Warbler Deployment

Tags: jrubyonrails, warbler

I am doing some testing to determine resource usage of a rails war. I have used Warbler to package the "15-minute Blog" application using Rails 2.3.5 and JRuby 1.4.0. I am deploying into Tomcat 6.0.24 and create multiple deployments by copying the blog.war file as blogN.war.

This worked great for the first 4 deployments but I can't seem to deploy any more than 4 instances of the war; in other words, the catalina.out log hangs with "Deploying web application archive blog5.war".

Any ideas on what the problem might be or how I might better trouble-shoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing PermGenSpace memory to "-XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m" corrected this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your log files, may be the case that your java process, in which tomcat executes, runs out of memory, see java parameters ( -Xmx -Xms ) and http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory . Increasing the available memory may allow you to run more instances of the application.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I had that set to -Xms512m and -Xmx512m. Starting up with 4 instances of the rails war left me with 375m free in the heap. Each instance reduced heap by about 25-30m so memory doesn't seem to be the issue.